# How do i get right width and height from image picked by Camera on Android?

Tags: java, android

I need to do the following:

1. Get a picture using the camera from Android...
2. Remove the background from the image and put in another background
3. save it

Im doing those 3 steps fine...
The problem is the image is saved in a small size (160 x 120).
When i get the result from camera i do this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Log.i("Test", "Width: " + photo.getWidth() + " Height: " + photo.getHeight());
```

It returns

```
Width: 160 Height: 120
```

The image that I am getting from "data" variable is 1280 x 960...

If I use

```
background= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, 1280, 960, false);
```

The image I get as bad quality...

How can I get the bitmap in the right size?!

Comment: Why are you returning the data as a bitmap extra? bitmap serialization might shrink the size - you're probably better off saving a file in the camera activity and returning the filename as the activity result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing out the image to a file and then returning the filename as the result:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  File pictureFile = new File(filename);

  try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
    fos.write(data);
    fos.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }

  Intent intent = this.getIntent();
  intent.putExtra("filename", filename);
  this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that just a few minuts before you post. hehehe Worked to me :)