# Android Camera Height and Width

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am currently doing a fault reporting page whereby the end user is able to report an `image` either by capturing using the camera or selecting a photo from the gallery. I am not sure why but when the `image` is taken using the camera, the `height` and `width` returned is about `220` by `180` which is a very blur image. I have tried looking online for other tutorials but my code seems to be the same as the others. Not too sure if it is my phone or what.

My code for Camera Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

My code after Capturing image from Camera:

```
thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

ivImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

I've tried getting the `width` and `height` before and after compression, both returns the same value.

Comment: Please don't tag Android Studio unless this is not the issue of Android Studio

Comment: Issue with the cam pixels.Change that in the camera app.

Comment: Its on 16:9 , 5312x2988 already. Lowering to 4:3 does help but increases the pixels by only 20 to 30.

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326517/how-do-i-get-right-width-and-height-from-image-picked-by-camera-on-android

Answer (score 0):

May be you should not compress the image rather simply use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath)` or any suitable method for getting your image from file into a `bitmap` (if not done already) and then set the bitmap object to the ImageResource like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And don't simply type cast the data received from intent. As far as I know about camera activity class, it will return a URI of the captured image. Try to receive it in `onActivityResult()` like this:

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            // Calculate the bitmap here according to the width of the device
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.captured_image)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```